# Receive an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when trying to access String array

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-sqlite, android-cursor

I have a model, `lineModel` that I am using to populate an array `items` for  my gridAdapter. **My model works fine when I populate the entries manually.** For example:

```
lineModel[] items = {
                new lineModel(2, "B", "", "#52D017", 5, 10, 30),
                new lineModel(3, "C", "", "#000000", 4, 8, 30),
};
```

However, when populating `items` with **SQLite** I receive the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Specifically:

```
04-15 15:50:21.322: E/AndroidRuntime(26804): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
04-15 15:50:21.322: E/AndroidRuntime(26804):    at com.idealiner.metrosleepuniversal.model.GridModel.getLines(GridModel.java:68)
```

**Line 68** is when I call lineModel and populate it with the values from cursor.

```
        items[i] = new lineModel(i, c.getString(c_line), c.getString(c_name), c.getString(c_ccolor), 0, 0, 0);
```

The method `getLines()` is supposed to return the object array, but somewhere in the `while()` loop I believe there is a problem, most likely when populating the array.

Any help/advice/guidance would be appreciated.

The entire method, `getLines`, is below:

```
public lineModel[] getLines() {

    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();


    String[] sqlSelect = {"*"}; 
    String sqlTables = "lines";

    qb.setTables(sqlTables);
    Cursor c = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, null, null,
            null, null, null);


    lineModel[] items = {};

    int i=0;

    int c_line      = c.getColumnIndex("line_id");
    int c_name      = c.getColumnIndex("line_name");
    int c_ccolor    = c.getColumnIndex("line_color");
    int c_tcolor    = c.getColumnIndex("text_color");


    c.moveToFirst();

    if (c != null) {
        while(c.moveToNext()) {
            items[i] = new lineModel(i, c.getString(c_line), c.getString(c_name), c.getString(c_ccolor), 0, 0, 0); 
            i++;
        }
        c.close();
    }

    return items;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `"*"` together with column names. You must either use only `"*"` or you must declare each column in the array. So, don't do it like this:

```
String[] sqlSelect = {"0 _id", "*"};
```

Add each one of them instead:

```
String[] sqlSelect = { "line_id", "line_name", "line_color", "text_color"};
```

Or:

```
String[] sqlSelect = { "*" };
```

You must also remove `c.moveToFirst()` call in order to avoid skipping the first row of the cursor, since `c.moveToNext()` already does this job for you.

Your array must also be large enough to hold all your items:

```
lineModel[] items = new lineModel[c.getCount()];
```

Besides that, keep in mind that class names in Java start with a capital letter.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you're creating a zero-length array:

```
lineModel[] items = {};
```

so there's no `items[i]` when you try assigning to it.

If you can use `c.getCount()`, as Flavio Faria suggests, set the initial length to that. Otherwise, I suggest you use an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), and `.add()` items to it as you go along. You can obtain the resulting array with `.toArray()`

In fact, you might consider using an ArrayList anyway and passing it up as the return value, ,that's very often a good idea.

Another alternative - which depends on how you use those line model items - is to pass an Iterator instead of an array (as what you're doing is essentially iterating into an array.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to try this.